# Change all directories with colon to whitespace

Tags: shell-script, debian, regular-expression

I got a lot of directories with colon.

For example

```
Main_Dir:
-Di_name: Test1-1
--files
-Di_name: Test2-2
--files
```

I want to remove (colon): amd replace it with whitespace or jsut delete it.

How can I achive this?

I am using Debian

Comment: Welcome, have you tried something so far?

Comment: In Debian you have the program `rename`, which it is very useful in such cases.

Comment: Please don't use whitespace. It will make everything more complicated. Also, are those the actual names? Do you have a directory named `-Di_name: Test1-1` or is it `-`Di_name: Test1-1`? And `--files`? Please show us some real examples (you can use `tree` to print the directory structure) so we can know what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Bash, Ksh or Zsh and that all directories are in the same level:

```bsh
# loop over the directories
for i in */; do
  # if they have a ':' semi-colon in their name
  # replace ':' using parameter expansion¹, (the space is already there)
  [[ "$i" = *:* ]] && mv -- "$i" "${i/:}"
done
```

---

¹ [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: `[[ $i = *:* ]]` or `case $i in *:*) mv ... esac` maybe. Or `if echo "$i" | grep -q :; then mv`

Comment: @ilkkachu much better, thanks

Comment: This is a bashism, just so you know. It will not work with `dash` or a strictly POSIX shell.

Answer (score 2):

Non POSIX-standard (because of the `-print0` and `-d ''` options), but pretty safe & bulletproof way:

```
cd /the/dir/containing/colon/dirnames
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*:*' -print0 | while read -r -d '' DIR ; do mv -- "$DIR" "$(echo "$DIR" | sed 's/://g')" ; done
```

Should work safely even if the directory name contains newline characters or other mischievous bytes.